# Bitrix24. Настройка бизнес-процессов и роботов в CRM

Tags: уведомления, битрикс24, crm, webhook

Всем доброго времени суток!

Работаю сейчас с CRM в Bitrix24, облачная версия.
Внутри CRM есть сделки, внутри сделок есть возможность создавать дела (activity).
Я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы при приближении к крайнему сроку activity, Bitrix отправил вебхук на мой обработчик. Там ставится время уведомления, например в момент истечения дедлайна, за 15 минут, за 1 день и т.д. Уведомление приходит только внутри самого Битрикса. А мне надо отправить это самое уведомление во внешний обработчик (через вебхук), который уже отправит нужное уведомление куда надо.
Поддержка Битрикса сказала, что обычными роботами этого не сделать, но возможно попробовать это реализовать через создание бизнес-процесса. Я в этом всего пару дней, покопался в конструкторе бизнес процессов, но не нашел ничего, что показалось бы тем, что надо.

Есть идеи, как это возможно сделать, если возможно вообще?
Заранее спасибо.

[image: Скрин раздела с созданием дела внутри сделки]